# Use sed to removing inline comments

Tags: sed, comments

I would like to use `sed` to remove all comments from a text file. Let's say that comment starts from 'A' character and end at the new line character. I would like to remove everything starting from the 'A' to the end of line including new line character. However, I don't want to remove comments starting from "AA".

Sample input:

```
%% comment to do not delete
% comment to delete
% another comment to delte
%% comment to do not delete
Some text % comment to delete
and some more text %% comment to do not delete
```

Desired output:

```
%% comment to do not delete
%% comment to do not delete
Some text and some more text %% comment to do not delete
```

Comment: The question is: What is a comment? comment starting with # or // or ''' or ' ?
Nvm you already said it. just didn't see it

Comment: It's LaTeX, so it's a % sign.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
$ perl -pe '/^[^%]*%%/ && next; s/%.*\n//g' file.txt
```

### Output

```
%% comment to do not delete
%% comment to do not delete
Some text and some more text %% comment to do not delete
```

### Note

If you need to change the file in-place, add `-i` switch (after your tests), so :

```
$ perl -i -pe '/^[^%]*%%/ && next; s/%.*\n//g' file.txt
```

---

Thanks [scrutinizer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073685/scrutinizer) for contributing.

Comment: It deleted all comments even this starting from "%%" and it didn't deleted new line character.

Comment: This one seems to work correctly. However, I would prefer `sed` version. Many thanks.

Comment: +1 Nice and simple. With `/^[^%]*%%/` instead of `/%%/` it would handle comment that needs to be deleted but that contains `%%` (before last line in my test input..)

Answer (score 2):

Perfect application of perl's negative look-behind assertion:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!%)%(?!%).*$//s' << END
%% comment to do not delete
% comment to delete
% another comment to delte
%% comment to do not delete
Some text % comment to delete
and some more text %% comment to do not delete
END
```

outputs

```
%% comment to do not delete
%% comment to do not delete
Some text and some more text %% comment to do not delete
```

The `s` flag ensures the dot will match a newline to achieve the "line joining" as requested.

This kind of regex matching can cause you problems, for instance if you have a line like

```
The date is `date +%Y%m%d` % this is a comment
```

You will end up with

```
The date is `date +
```

If your actual comment *requires* whitespace around it, you could use this regex:

```
(^| )%( .*|)$
```

which means

- the beginning of line OR a space
- followed by the comment char
- followed by (a space and zero or more chars) OR nothing
- followed by end of line

Comment: Looks good at first glance, but it fails with the latest line of this sample : http://pastealacon.com/31972

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

**2nd update**

```
$ sed -e '/^%[^%]/d' -e 's/ %[^%]*$/@/' -e :a -e '/@/N; s/\n//; ta' input | sed 's/@/ /g'
%% comment to do not delete
%% comment to do not delete
Some text and some more text %% comment to do not delete
```

Comment: It doesn't work for more complex input. See edited question for an example. Thanks.

Comment: @MichalPietras - howabout now?

Comment: you need to join a line which have a comment not at the beginning with the next line? Apart from that my sed delivers...

Comment: Yeah, I need to delete new line character as well. In case of comments starting at the beginning of a line it's supposed to delete entire line. Otherwise, it's supposed to joint it with the next line. Like in the example.

Comment: It deleted to much on my computer. Maybem I have a different version of `sed`. I use OS X.

Comment: Using gnu sed here, I give up :-)

Comment: I can confirm that it works with GNU sed but there are still some issues. It deletes all new line character after reaching the firs `%` comment.

Answer (score 0):

*edit* Added changes so it works well on last line in the file...
Try:

```
sed -e :a -e '/^[^%]*%%/n; /%/{s/%.*//; N; s/\n//;};ta' file
```

Tested with input:

```
%% comment to do not delete
% comment to delete
% another comment to delte
%
%% comment to do not delete
Some text % comment to delete
Some more text % more comment to delete
and some more text %% comment to do not delete
fdgdfgdgdgd %
gfdgd
some text followed by %% comment to not delete that contains a % somewhere
some text followed by % comment to delete that contains %% somewhere
hello there
```

output:

```
%% comment to do not delete
%% comment to do not delete
Some text Some more text and some more text %% comment to do not delete
fdgdfgdgdgd gfdgd
some text followed by %% comment to not delete that contains a % somewhere
some text followed by hello there
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Expression Order with Sed

With sed, the order of instructions can be important. For example:

```
$ sed -ne '/^% /d; /[^%]%.*/ {s/%.*//; n}; p' /tmp/corpus 
%% comment to do not delete
%% comment to do not delete
and some more text %% comment to do not delete
```

In this example, the sed script performs its tasks in this order:

1. Suppress output.
2. Delete lines that start with a single percent sign.
3. Use substitution to remove all characters from a single percent to end-of-line, then append the next line to the pattern space without a newline.
4. Print the pattern space.

This script works with the corpus you provided in your question. It is not guaranteed to work with any other corpus without modifications, and explicitly does not work if the lines you append to the pattern space contain comment characters.